# how to open an array of object based on the name

Tags: javascript

I have an array with multiple objects having the same name. How can I segregate the array based on the name?

I tried with map, filter but didn't work finally I used reduce also but not getting the output.

```
const result = Object.values(this.optionsArr.reduce((a, c) => {
        a[c.name] = a[c.name] || {name: c.name};
        a[c.name].options.push(c.options);
        return a;
      }, {})).map(item => ({...item, accessDetails: Object.values(item.accessDetails)}));
```

Input:

```
[
{name: "audio", options: [
    {name:'true', value: 'T'},
    {name:'false', value: 'F'},
    {name:'yes', value: 'Y'}]
},
{name: "video", options: [
    {name:'true', value: 'T'},
    {name:'false', value: 'F'},
    {name:'yes', value: 'Y'}]
},
{name: "call", options: [
    {name:'true', value: 'T'},
    {name:'false', value: 'F'},
    {name:'yes', value: 'Y'}]
}]
```

Expected Ouput:

```
const arr = [{name: "audio", options:{name:'true', value: 'T'}},
{name: "audio", options:{name:'false', value: 'F'}},
{name: "audio", options:{name:'yes', value: 'Y'}},
{name: "video", options:{name:'true', value: 'T'}},
{name: "video", options:{name:'yes', value: 'Y'}},
{name: "video", options:{name:'false', value: 'F'}},
{name: "call", options:{name:'true', value: 'T'}},
{name: "call", options:{name:'No', value: 'N'}},
{name: "call", options:{name:'false', value: 'F'}}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input is an array of object so array.map:

```
let newArray = []
input.map(function(item) {
  item.options.map(function(option) {
    newArray.push({name:item.name, options: option})
  })
})
console.log(newArray);
```

should work

Answer (score 1):

You should use map to transform the array,

```js
arr = arr.map((element) => {
    const temp = [];
    element.options.forEach(option => {
        temp.push({
            name: element.name,
            options: option
        });
    })
    return temp;
}).flat();
```

Comment: This will produce an array of arrays, the desired output is a single level array.

Comment: Understood. Adding a flat at the end flattens the array. Have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `.reduce` is the way to go, here is a way of doing it:

```js
const input = [{name: "audio", options:[{name:'true', value: 'T'},{name:'false', value: 'F'},{name:'yes', value: 'Y'}]},
    {name: "video", options:[{name:'true', value: 'T'},{name:'false', value: 'F'},{name:'yes', value: 'Y'}]},
    {name: "call", options:[{name:'true', value: 'T'},{name:'false', value: 'F'},{name:'yes', value: 'Y'}]}];

const output = input.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const newEntries = cur.options.reduce((a, c) => ([...a, { ...cur, options: c }]), []);
  return [
      ...acc,
      ...newEntries
    ];
},[]);

console.log(output);
```

In this example I'm reducing the original array (`input`) and then I'm reducing each entry's `options` array to create a new element for each of them, and then I'm adding these new entries to the return array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sort` method and [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

**Try This:**

```
arr.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
```

Comment: That's weird, it works for me. It doesn't return anything? It's supposed to give you a new array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let output = [];

input.map(item => {
  item.options.forEach(o => {
    output.push({
      name: item.name,
      options: {
        name: o.name,
        value: o.value
      }
    });
  });
});
```